# Парсер на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу скрипт на Python. Возник вопрос, подскажите как решить. Есть текст на английском, нужно из всего этого текста взять только номера телефонов (именно которые начинаются с цифры 8), бываетдаже что в тексте нет ни одного номера, такой текст не нужен. P.S. это парсер веб страницы, я парсю (как правильно звучит не знаю, паршу, короче пашит программа) блоки, в этих блоках этот самый текст на английском. Там куча воды, мне нужны лишь номера телефонов, которые начинаются с цифры 8. Вот html теги на сайте:

```
<div data-th="Details" data-group="calData" class="tblContent5">
Cirrus Logic Inc. (CRUS) will host a conference call at 5:00 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q4 20 earnings results.

To access the live webcast, log on to www.cirrus.com

For a replay call, dial (41.) 6..-4..2 or (800) 5..-8..7 (Access Code: 91....).
```

и так около 10 дивов, нужно спарсить из всего этого текста лишь номер телефона, который начинается с 8: (800) 5..-8..7 (именно так и и менно с точками). split'ом я так понимаю тут не подойдет, как по другому?

Comment: Регулярные выражения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .startswith('8') в помощь

```py
    string = 'your div blocks'
    arr = string.split(' ')
    for el in range(0, len(arr)):
       elem = arr[el]
       if elem.startswith('8'):
         print(elem, arr[el + 1])
```

Comment: Зачем такие сложности в цикле? Можно сразу идти по самим элементам: `for elem in arr: if elem.startswith("8")`